# How to fix “only available in ES6” linter errors?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, jslint, eslint, sublimelinter

I am trying to add a linter to my Express application and am getting several linter errors about ES6, i.e. `‘export’ is only available in ES6 (use esnext option)`, `’const’ is only available in JavaScript 1.7`, and `’arrow function syntax’ is only available in Javascript 1.7`. I’m not sure how to get rid of these errors—any help would be appreciated. I currently have tried installing several things, including Sublime Text 2 linter and babel-eslint, but might be approaching this wrong.

From relevant package.json:

```
{
"dependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
  "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
  "botkit-sms": "^1.1.0",
  "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "jwt-simple": "^0.5.0",
  "mongoose": "^4.6.3",
  "passport": "^0.3.2",
  "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
  "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  "request": "^2.76.0",
  "routific": "0.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
  "eslint": "^2.13.1",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.4.2",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
  "nodemon": "^1.9.2"
}
```

}

.babelrc:

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

.eslintrc:

```
{
extends: ["airbnb", "esnext"],
parser: "babel-eslint",
env: {
  browser: false,
  node: true,
  es6: true
},
rules: {
  strict: 0,
  quotes: [2, "single"],
  no-else-return: 0,
  new-cap: ["error", {"capIsNewExceptions": ["Router"]}],
  no-console: 0,
  import/no-unresolved: [2, { commonjs: true}],
  no-unused-vars: ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "none" }],
  no-underscore-dangle: 0,
  arrow-body-style: ["error", "always"],
  no-shadow: ["error", { "allow": ["done", "res", "cb", "err", "resolve", "reject"] }],
  no-use-before-define: ["error", { "functions": false }],
  max-len: 0
},
plugins: [
  'import'
],
ecmaFeatures: {
  jsx: true,
  modules: true
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the esnext to true in Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublimelinter -> Settings-User worked for me

```
{
  "jshint_options":
    {
        "esnext": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must get rid of esnext
This is my node .eslintrc:

```
    {
  "extends" : "airbnb",
  "rules": {
   // disable requiring trailing commas because it might be nice to revert to
   // being JSON at some point, and I don t want to make big changes now.
   "comma-dangle": 0,
   // we can use escape and template strings
   "quotes": [1, "single", {"avoidEscape": true, "allowTemplateLiterals": true}],
   "max-len": [0],
   "no-console": 0,
   "no-param-reassign": 0
 },
 "globals": { "ENV": true },
 "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jasmine": true
  }
}
```

And these are my devDependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ecmaFeatures` configuration setting goes under [`parserOptions`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options).

```
...
plugins: [
  'import'
],
parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
        jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module'
},
...
```

And you should use `sourceType: 'module'` instead of `modules: true`.